# Convert a tab- and newline-delimited string to pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I have a string of the following format:

```
aString = '123\t456\t789\n321\t654\t987 ...'
```

And I would like to convert it to a pandas DataFrame

```
frame:
  123 456 789
  321 654 987
  ...
```

I have tried to convert it to a Python list:

```
stringList = aString.split('\n')
```

which results in:

```
stringList = ['123\t456\t789',
              '321\t654\t987',
              ...
             ]
```

Have no idea what to do next.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

one option is list comprehension with `str.split`

```
pd.DataFrame([x.split('\t') for x in stringList], columns=list('ABC'))

     A   B   C
0   123 456 789
1   321 654 987
```

You can use `StringIO`

```
from io import StringIO
pd.read_csv(StringIO(aString), sep='\t', header=None)

    0   1   2
0   123 456 789
1   321 654 987
```

Comment: Is there any way not to use a for loop, as the string contains tens of thousands of lines.

Comment: Thank you Chris:) It worked like a charm :)

Comment: To save future readers an extra trip into [`read_csv` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), `header` is a 0-based row number (in the CSV); to override the column names, pass a `names=['col1', 'col2']`