# From large ugly input text file to pretty little dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, split

I have a large input text file (>10'000 lines), of which you can find an extract below:

```
$
SPC           10  507901  123456     0.0
SPC           10  507902  123456     0.0
SPC           10  507903  123456     0.0
$
GRID      100001  100000 8.17119-0.68585 1.92194  100010
GRID      100002  100000 7.73198-0.94529 1.73439  100010
GRID      100003  100000 7.28772-0.97244 1.54514  100010
GRID      100004  100000 6.76982-0.71715 1.32471  100010
```

I am trying to extract all of the lines starting with GRID and put them in a dataframe of 7 columns. Each column is defined by 8 characters (thanks Nastran). For example, for the first line of GRID shown above, it should be divided as such:

```
|GRID    |  100001|  100000| 8.17119|-0.68585| 1.92194|  100010|
```

My code:

```
model_without_grid = list()
model_just_grid = list()

with open('MODELE1', encoding='utf-8') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if line.startswith('GRID') :
            model_just_grid.append(line)
        else :
            model_without_grid.append(line)
```

Gives me a nice list of all the lines starting with GRID.
Now I want to use the split function to divide each lines into multiple columns of a dataframe.

By using this question:
[Convert a tab- and newline-delimited string to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54102980/convert-a-tab-and-newline-delimited-string-to-pandas-dataframe/54103026)

I tried:

```
grid_pd = pd.DataFrame([x.split('        ') for x in model_just_grid],columns=list('1234567'))
```

But get the following error:

```
ValueError: 7 columns passed, passed data had 1 columns
```

Of course, if I take out the columns part, I get a dataframe with one column exactly identical to my list....

I then tried:

```
aaa  = grid_pd[0].str.split('.{8}')
```

And

```
aaa  = grid_pd[0].str.extractall('(.{8})')
```

But the first one creates an empty dataframe and the second one a multi-index dataframe. By unstacking it,

```
 aaa = aaa.unstack()
```

it does give me my dataframe, but there has to be a cleaner solution...

Anyone know how to solve my issue? The manoeuver seems simple enough but I can't figure out a clean way to proceed...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Is the header (lines between `$`) fixed number of lines? Is it safe to assume that when `GRID` ines start they continue to end of file?

Comment: Sadly not, no, and there are multiple tables of various size and columns in addition to text within my input file, so I can't simply put the whole ionput file into a dataframe and filter it afterwards

Comment: Note that the accepted answer will not give the wanted output since for example "8.17119-0.68585" will not be split into separate columns.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Shaido, I just changed it.

Comment: I changed my answer. @elle.delle, please check it.

Comment: Besides, @Shaido's answer has two problems. First, It had hard code in it, so it has poor portability. Second, and the most important problem, every cell in the result may have extra blanks. Try `df.loc[0, 0]` you will get 'GRID    ', there are four blanks follow the word 'GRID'.

Comment: @XuQiushi for the hard code, the two parameters are defined by variables in my code so that shouldn't be an issue. I just tried your answer again and it worked, thanks a lot for your help, I appreciate it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to split each row into 7 equal-sized segments before creating the dataframe. This could be done by looping over all relevant strings and splitting them according to the condition.

For example:

```
chunks, chunk_size = 56, 8

rows = [[x[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, chunks, chunk_size)] for x in model_without_grid]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

Result:

```
       0         1       2        3        4          5      6
0   GRID    100001  100000  8.17119 -0.68585    1.92194 100010
1   GRID    100002  100000  7.73198 -0.94529    1.73439 100010
2   GRID    100003  100000  7.28772 -0.97244    1.54514 100010
3   GRID    100004  100000  6.76982 -0.71715    1.32471 100010
```